# Eisenstein series evaluated at $2i$

Tags: nt.number-theory, zeta-functions, eisenstein-series, binary-quadratic-forms

Consider the real analytic Eisenstein series defined by
$$
E(z,s) := \sum_{\gamma\in\Gamma_\infty\setminus\Gamma} Im(\gamma z)^s
$$
where as usual, $\Gamma=SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ and $\Gamma_\infty$ is the subgroup of translations. Initially the Eisenstein series is defined on a suitable half plane (in the $s$ variable) and can be continued meromorphically to the whole complex plane. The varible $z$ belongs to the upper half plane.

The particular property that I am interested in is the evaluation of $E(z,s)$ at the so called CM points. In particular, for simplicity, let us consider $E(i,s)$. It is well known (and in fact easily computed) that
$$
\zeta(2s)E(i,s) = \zeta_{\mathbb{Q}(i)}(s)
$$
where $\zeta_{\mathbb{Q}(i)}(s)$ is the Dedekind zeta function associated to the number field $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

This can be generalized to other special points to get the corresponding Epstein zeta functions. I am interested in understanding $E(2i,s)$. If we proceed to do the calculations as in the case of $E(i,s)$ we end with the sum

$$
\sum_{(c,d)\neq (0,0)} \frac{1}{(4c^2+d^2)^s}.
$$

Is there any standard formula for such  a sum?

My guess is that we will end up with the zeta function associated to some class in some ray class group of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ but I am not able to prove this.